# Using the ruby-trello gem, how can I determine whether a board is public or not?

Tags: ruby, trello

I'm using the [ruby-trello gem](https://github.com/jeremytregunna/ruby-trello) to access the [Trello API](https://trello.readme.io/reference#introduction).

I tried this:

```
> board = Trello::Member.find('me').boards.first
> board.prefs['permissionLevel']
=> "org"
> board.organization.prefs
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):20
NoMethodError (undefined method `prefs' for #<Trello::Organization:0x0000562900d7bb88>)
```

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using the ruby-trello gem, how can I determine whether an organization is public or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980722/using-the-ruby-trello-gem-how-can-i-determine-whether-an-organization-is-public)

Answer (score 0):

Building off [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50989065/9381758), here's a workaround:

```
def org_public?(org)
  # If org comes from a board, it may be nil. We'll skip the philosophical conundrums
  # and assume an inaccessible or non-existent board is not public.
  return false if org.nil?

  path = "/organizations/#{org.id}/prefs"
  response = org.client.get(path)
  JSON.parse(response.body)['permissionLevel']
end

def board_public?(board)
  # Sometimes board.organization will return a 401 error when there is a board. 
  # Maybe it's been deleted?
  org = board.organization rescue nil

  # If board is public, sure
  return true if board.prefs['permissionLevel'] == 'public' 

  # If board permission tied to org
  return true if board.prefs['permissionLevel'] == 'org' && org_public?(org)

  # Any other cases I'm missing?
  false 
end

> board = Trello::Member.find('me').boards.first
> board_public?(board)
=> true
> board = Trello::Member.find('me').boards[1]
> board_public?(board)
=> false
```