# Using the ruby-trello gem, how can I determine whether an organization is public or not?

Tags: ruby, trello

This question was prompted by this one:

- [Using the ruby-trello gem, how can I determine whether a board is public or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979870/using-the-ruby-trello-gem-how-can-i-determine-whether-a-board-is-public-or-not)

In the Trello API, I see both [boards](https://trello.readme.io/reference#board-object) and [organizations](https://trello.readme.io/reference#organization-object) offer a `prefs` object with a `permissionLevel` values.

However, it appears the gem only returns these `prefs` values for the board:

```
> board = Trello::Member.find('me').boards.first
> board.prefs['permissionLevel']
=> "org"
> org = Trello::Member.find('me').organizations.first
> org.prefs['permissionLevel']
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):11
NoMethodError (undefined method `prefs' for #<Trello::Organization:0x00007feb54459fd8>)
```

Is there any way to get the organization's permission level using the gem?

Comment: Why are you creating two questions for the same issue, why not edit the first one ?

Comment: I seem to remember seeing some questions critiqued for not focusing on a single question. Also, although they seem to be related to the same root cause, I could see them having different answers.

Comment: No both your questions are same, just querying different objects

Comment: They are not even querying different objects. In both questions you show `Board` responds to `prefs` and `Organization` does not.

Comment: That assumes that I'm even going about it the right way querying the org object in the other question. The docs don't make it explicit that that is the only option. Please consider both answers I've posted and maybe this too: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/06/21/rolling-out-the-welcome-wagon-june-update/?cb=1

Comment: What do you mean "going about it the right way" the error is identical and the code is open source. I certainly have no objection to the question you asked (and trust me I have a tendency to be more welcoming than most) but asking the same question twice in the span of 2 hours in not necessary. Please note whether or not you should even do this has been asked in a duplicitous manner https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128226/can-i-ask-same-question-again-if-nobody-has-answered

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround using the gem:

```
> org = Trello::Member.find('me').organizations.first
> path = "/organizations/#{org.id}/prefs"
> response = org.client.get(path)
> org_prefs = JSON.parse(response.body)
=> {"permissionLevel"=>"public", "orgInviteRestrict"=>[], "externalMembersDisabled"=>false, "associatedDomain"=>nil, "googleAppsVersion"=>1, "boardVisibilityRestrict"=>{"private"=>"org", "org"=>"org", "public"=>"org"}}
> org_prefs['permissionLevel']
=> "public"
```

Answer (score 0):

The gem you are using does not support `prefs` in organization objects, you can verify that [here](https://github.com/jeremytregunna/ruby-trello/blob/master/lib/trello/organization.rb) but the actual [Trello API](https://developers.trello.com/v1.0/reference#organization-object) does have that field so you can either look for other gems that provide you that data or call the API directly  without using the gem